# jQuery sortable, сортировка блоков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день! Есть задача отсортировать блоки внутри одного блока.
Html имеет такую структуру:

```
<div class="sortable">
   <div class="file-preview"></div>
   <div class="file-preview"></div>
```

Нужно чтобы div-ы с классом file-preview можно было сортировать, в sortable могут быть и другие div-ы

Я делаю сейчас

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "file-preview"
});
```

Но так не работает, подскажите, пожалуйста. как решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать параметр `items`: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    items: ".file-preview"
  });
  $( ".sortable div" ).disableSelection();
});
```